# unresolved external symbol error: not able to solve it

Tags: c++

I am getting below unresolved external symbol error while compiling the code. I am using third party library. so using third party library namespace while compiling the code.

> std_uss.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "`__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl os_std::os_throw_length_error(void)`" (`__imp_?os_throw_length_error@os_std@@YAXXZ`) referenced in function "`private: char * __thiscall os_std::basic_string<char,class os_std::char_traits_char,class os_std::allocator<char> >::allocate(unsigned int)`" (`?allocate@?$basic_string@DVchar_traits_char@os_std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@os_std@@AAEPADI@Z`)

I found os_throw_length_error function in one of the files of third part library but did not find any function similar to ::allocator in the code. I did not used standard std namespace since I want compiler to use third party namespace.

If I use `using namespace std` which is standard then my compilation is successful but then some definitions like string are getting referenced to visual studio string rather than third party string function.

Comment: third party library is ospace from recursion software

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the import library (.lib file) for the third-party DLL to your project. In Visual Studio, that would be in the project properties, under Linker/Input/Additional Dependecies

Comment: i added all the .lib files in additional dependencies. still i am seeing the same problem.

Comment: Try to run DUMPBIN /EXPORTS on the .lib file to see if the symbol your linker complains about (or a similar one) is in the list of exported symbols.